# Why PHPUnit into Laravel return "No tests executed!" at execution feature tests

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I have file tests/Feature/InvoicePaymentTest.php, he contains are three tests. First and second are tests is executed correctly. Third test has return "No tests executed!", and not return error.
[image: illustration of how this happens]

My code scheme

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

// use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class SubscriptionInvoicePaymentTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testFirst()
    {
        // this test correctly exeqted
    }

    public function testSecond()
    {
        // this test correctly exeqted
    }

    public function nextPaymentTest()
    {
        // this test return "No tests executed!" as seen in the screenshot
    }
}
```

My phpunit.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="BROADCAST_DRIVER" value="fake"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="dbName"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

What could be the problem? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phpunit a method should be either prefixed with `test` or have the `@test` annotation in order to be run.